# When Can I Start Killing People?

Tags: mirrors-edge

It was my impression that you're not allowed to kill anyone at the beginning of Mirror's Edge, but then suddenly, somewhere in the middle of the game, you're allowed to kill people. The game does not inform you of this.

At what point does Mirror's Edge start allowing me to kill people without failing the level?

Comment: There's an achievement for completing the game without killing anyone - which is part of the point of the game. Practice disarming and running instead.

Comment: @ChrisF too easy.  I'm curious about a bodycount run, would be really different

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first time you get a pistol or a shotgun from a policeman, you can kill them without failing the level. I'm not sure when exactly this is, but it happens during the second or third level.

Comment: Isn't it the first level (Tutorial excluded) where you encounter a policeman and can disarm him, including killing all others?